# What Carousel Are they Using

Tags: html, css, slider, carousel

Just came across a slider-carousel I really liked and was inspecting the code to see what they have used. I just can't seem to find the exact one they are using.

Anyone happen to know what carousel they are using :

```
http://forayclothing.co.uk/
```

Comment: [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27690032/3436942)

Answer (score 0):

it is a wordpress theme called oneclick with the carousel, view the source then the bottom of the page  `http://forayclothing.co.uk/wp-content/themes/oneclick/js/carousels.js?ver=4.0`