# Basic slideshow program

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

This is just a basic slide show using js but I'm not getting the output. I want it to perform automatic slideshow, should I add jquery script into my program. Please help me out

```
<script>
var images = new Array(); 
images[0] = new Image(); 
images[0].src = "first.jpg"; 
images[1] = new Image();
images[1].src = "second.jpg";
images[2] = new Image();
images[2].src = "third.jpg";

</script>
</head>
<body>
<img src="first.jpg" id="slide" width="500" height="500" />

<script type="text/javascript">


var step=0;

function slideit(){

 document.getElementById('slide').src = images[step].src;
 if (step<2)
  step++;
 else
  step=0;

 setTimeout("slideit()",2500);
}

slideit();

</body>
```

Comment: The only real reason to add jquery would be because you want animation.  If that's not important to you, this should work fine.  What do you mean you're not getting output?

Comment: The images are not changing.

Comment: [any help to you?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27690032/3436942)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `setInterval()` instead of `setTimeout()`, also your code could be simplified to following.

```js
var images = ['http://dummyimage.com/300x100/025870/fff', 'http://dummyimage.com/300x100/456e02/fff', 'http://dummyimage.com/300x100/6e2b02/fff'];
var step = 0;

setInterval(function() {
  document.getElementById('slide').src = images[step++ % images.length];
}, 2500);
```

```html
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x100/025870/fff" id="slide" width="300" height="100" />
```

Notice the use of modulus(`%`). To understand it better, here is what's happening:

```
1st iteration: (step++ % images.length) ⇒ (0 % 3) ⇒ 0,  
2nd iteration: (step++ % images.length) ⇒ (1 % 3) ⇒ 1,   
3rd iteration: (step++ % images.length) ⇒ (2 % 3) ⇒ 2,   
4th iteration: (step++ % images.length) ⇒ (3 % 3) ⇒ 0,   
5th iteration: (step++ % images.length) ⇒ (4 % 3) ⇒ 1 and so on...
```

Every time the value of `step` is divisible by the number of images, if rolls back to `0`.

Comment: I just set up a jfiddle to  show this exact thing.  Chip is correct.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked and that's a wonderful explanation.