# 3D carousel with JQuery and CSS - not rendering correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to implement a CD carousel with JQuery and CSS and I've been browsing StackOverflow for some ideas. I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27640896/3d-carousel-effect). I've been trying to implement the code for idea 2 on my own machine and it doesn't seem to be working.

Here's all the code:

```js
/* Create an array to hold the different image positions */
var itemPositions = [];
var numberOfItems = $('#scroller .item').length;

/* Assign each array element a CSS class based on its initial position */
function assignPositions() {
  for (var i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++) {
    if (i === 0) {
      itemPositions[i] = 'left-hidden';
    } else if (i === 1) {
      itemPositions[i] = 'left';
    } else if (i === 2) {
      itemPositions[i] = 'middle';
    } else if (i === 3) {
      itemPositions[i] = 'right';
    } else {
      itemPositions[i] = 'right-hidden';
    }
  }
  /* Add each class to the corresponding element */
  $('#scroller .item').each(function(index) {
    $(this).addClass(itemPositions[index]);
  });
}

/* To scroll, we shift the array values by one place and reapply the classes to the images */
function scroll(direction) {
  if (direction === 'prev') {
    itemPositions.push(itemPositions.shift());
  } else if (direction === 'next') {
    itemPositions.unshift(itemPositions.pop());
  }
  $('#scroller .item').removeClass('left-hidden left middle right right-hidden').each(function(index) {
    $(this).addClass(itemPositions[index]);
  });
}

/* Do all this when the DOMs ready */
$(document).ready(function() {

    console.log("DOM ready")

  assignPositions();
  var autoScroll = window.setInterval("scroll('next')", 4000);

  /* Hover behaviours */
  $('#scroller').hover(function() {
    window.clearInterval(autoScroll);
    $('.nav').stop(true, true).fadeIn(200);
  }, function() {
    autoScroll = window.setInterval("scroll('next')", 4000);
    $('.nav').stop(true, true).fadeOut(200);
  });

  /* Click behaviours */
  $('.prev').click(function() {
    scroll('prev');
  });
  $('.next').click(function() {
    scroll('next');
  });

});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4D4D4D 0, #4D4D4D 180px, #939393 400px);
}

.warning {
  margin: 10px auto 0;
  width: 500px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#scroller {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 50px 0;
  -webkit-perspective: 500px;
  -moz-perspective: 500px;
  -o-perspective: 500px;
}

#scroller .item {
  width: 500px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-reflect: below 0px -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(transparent), color-stop(.85, transparent), to(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)));
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 0;
}
/* Since inset shadows don't play nice with images, we'll create a pseudo element and apply our image styling to that instead */

#scroller .item:before {
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 500px;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

#scroller .item img {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#scroller .left {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(25deg) translateX(-320px) skewY(-5deg) scale(0.4, 0.6);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(25deg) translateX(-320px) skewY(-5deg) scale(0.4, 0.6);
  -o-transform: rotateY(25deg) translateX(-320px) skewY(-5deg) scale(0.4, 0.6);
}

#scroller .middle {
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg) translateX(0) scale(1);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg) translateX(0) scale(1);
  -o-transform: rotateY(0deg) translateX(0) scale(1);
}

#scroller .right {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-25deg) translateX(320px) skewY(5deg) scale(0.4, 0.6);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(-25deg) translateX(320px) skewY(5deg) scale(0.4, 0.6);
  -o-transform: rotateY(-25deg) translateX(320px) skewY(5deg) scale(0.4, 0.6);
}

#scroller .left-hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(25deg) translateX(-430px) skewY(-5deg) scale(0.3, 0.5);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(25deg) translateX(-430px) skewY(-5deg) scale(0.3, 0.5);
  -o-transform: rotateY(25deg) translateX(-430px) skewY(-5deg) scale(0.3, 0.5);
}

#scroller .right-hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-25deg) translateX(430px) skewY(5deg) scale(0.3, 0.5);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(-25deg) translateX(430px) skewY(5deg) scale(0.3, 0.5);
  -o-transform: rotateY(-25deg) translateX(430px) skewY(5deg) scale(0.3, 0.5);
}

.nav {
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 170px 0 0;
  z-index: 2;
  display: none;
}
.prev,
.next {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
  border-radius: 15px;
  color: #E4E4E4;
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 26px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.next {
  left: inherit;
  right: 15px;
}

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="test.js"></script>
        <link href="test.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="scroller">
          <div class="nav">
            <a class="prev">&laquo;</a>
            <a class="next">&raquo;</a>
          </div>
          <a class="item" href="#">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/5Mk3EfW.jpg" />
          </a>
          <a class="item" href="#">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/79aU67L.jpg" />
          </a>
          <a class="item" href="#">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/x3wSoFU.jpg" />
          </a>
          <a class="item" href="#">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/27fTqbA.jpg" />
          </a>
          <a class="item" href="#">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/RjdFV6n.jpg" />
          </a>
          <a class="item" href="#">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/6W8JOza.jpg" />
          </a>
          <a class="item" href="#">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/rwLY1JH.jpg" />
          </a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can see that in the above snippet the code works fine and as it should, however when I try to run it on my own machine it doesn't work correctly. Below is what it looks like when I load the HTML file on Chrome and Firefox:

[Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svfm7.jpg)
[Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgGWx.jpg)

You can see it's not loading all the elements properly. This has stumped me since the code is literally identical here and on my machine. I'm hosting using Pythons `http.server` function.

The browser consoles don't give any errors that would hint to what is happening. In fact, both consoles log 'DOM ready' in the `$(document).ready` function in the JS file, so seemingly everything should be fine.

What could be causing this to happen?

EDIT: I tried changing the order of the script tags in the header but it didn't help

Comment: As it's a moving something, a screenshot doesn't cover all aspects of the question - for example, is your problem that nothing animates or that it does animate, but the side images don't show up (as if there was overflow:hidden set on the containing div)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your code locally using npm-lite and found the same error until I moved

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="test.js"></script>
```

out of the `<head></head>` tags and after the rest of the html code but right before the closing `</body>` tag.

I tested this in both chrome and firefox and it's now working perfectly